# How can I read the content of a file if I have a ParcelFileDescriptor

Tags: android

In android, I get a ParcelFileDescriptor after I call mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(contentURI, "r")

but how can I read the content of the file into a string or Stringbuffer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` instead. Then, you just use normal Java I/O to read it in.